# problems with x:Bind Mode=OneWay

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, xbind

I'm using x:Bind with mode=OneWay.

```
<CommandBar
    DefaultLabelPosition="Bottom"
    RelativePanel.RightOf="AutoSuggestBoxSearchItem">
    <AppBarButton
        x:Name="DetailsButton"
        Icon="Contact"
        Label="View details"
        IsEnabled="{x:Bind converters:Converters.IsNotNull(ViewModel.SelectedItem), Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <AppBarButton
        x:Name="DeleteButton"
        Icon="Delete"
        Label="Delete"
        IsEnabled="{x:Bind converters:Converters.IsNotNull(ViewModel.SelectedItem), Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <AppBarSeparator/>
    <AppBarButton
        x:Name="AddButton"
        Icon="Add"
        Label="Add"/>
```

IsNotNull check's if object is not null.

```
public class Converters
{
    public static bool  IsNotNull(object value) => value != null;
}
```

ViewModel.SectedItem show's selected item in datagrid.
So when i select item in DataGrid, app bar buttons must set property isEnabled to true.

But:
[2 first button on the top must be available, but thay aren't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IylLl.png)

Comment: for one way and two way databindings you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged , more here  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingmode

Answer (score 1):

Create a property and bind it to IsEnabled as shown below
    IsEnabled="{x:Bind propertyName)

On the property setter use 
OnPropertyChanged("propertyName")